# Configurable product selectable attribute

Tags: configurable-product, custom-options, associate-products

This question is related to a previous one I asked here: [Simple vs Virtual Products for Virtual Products as Configurable Products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40773/simple-vs-virtual-products-for-virtual-products-as-configurable-products/40793#40793)

While creating a configurable product to associate our products with I forgot that I have to create a selectable option. That would seem trivial for something like a shirt size or color.

In our case, the selectable option is the price of the associated product – think calling card or gift card denomination.

Is it possible, or is there a similar solution I'm not considering, that would allow us to create configurable products based on (virtual) associated products' prices or names?

The reason we want to use individual products over custom options is to have the ability to track inventory of individual products and, more importantly, to be able to assign attributes to the individual denominations. One example of this would be an attribute that assigns a particular denomination to a particular fulfillment warehouse; where some denominations (selectable options) of a configurable product might be filled from warehouse A, some from warehouse B, and some from C. The "warehouses" are essentially different API integrations.